# How to convert a text into clickable link using a networkD3 widget in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I have created a Forcenetwork and I want when I click on any node it should provide its description along with a hyperlink on the same page. So that anyone can click that link and get more information about that node.I have a csv file where I have provided all related link in a column called "hyperlink".

I want that link to be clickable.

Thank you in advance.

**This is my Code:**

```
    library(shiny)
    library(networkD3)

    links
```

Comment: Currently the code in your question only includes the line `links` with little context. Was this by accident? You may need to edit your question to include more details, as this is insufficient to provide help. Good luck!

Comment: Please see `?htmltools::builder` (a-tag) or `?shiny::actionLink`.

Comment: @ismirsehregal while this question is very poorly written and has very little context, it seems very clear to me that it is not a duplicate of that other question and that the other question will not answer this user’s question. Wouldn’t it be better to ask for more detaI/context?

Comment: @CJYetman yes, you are right. I just reopened the question. kumari sinam please provide us with a [reproducible example](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html#getting-help).

Comment: Hello **@ismirsehregal and @CJYetman**

Sorry, for late response.

Thank you so much for your support.

I resolved this issue. 

Thank you so much.